# Node can't read Access-control-allow-origin header

Tags: node.js, express, header, http-status-code-503

okay so this is pretty odd i have the following server.js file with the following code:

```
    app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    if (res.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        // Set custom headers for CORS
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    }
    next();
});
```

Now the domain that my system calls is `api.example.com`

I call this from another site called `angular.example.com`

When i do this i get the following error message in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/api/componentsByModule/125 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://angular.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

But as you can see from my above code it should set the headers on all requests

So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are both of the sites you are using your own sites? Access-Allow-Control-Origin setting is managed by the site owner on their server. I have not devised a way to allow it from within my app from my domain accessing another's domain yet.  Interestingly, cURL calls work fine, and HURL.it is great for reviewing the response headers of a call to a given URL.  But, if you don't own that domain you're attempting to access, or have control over the server's configuration files, you cannot inject allowed access to cross site scripting (XSS/CORS) hurl it here: (https://www.hurl.it/)

Comment: @MikeHorstmann both of my sites are managed by me however i have serveral subdomains that points to the same ip

Comment: `app.use` is the more idiomatic way to add middleware in express instead of the more verbose `app.all('/*'`.

Comment: If you `console.log` in there or debug to a breakpoint, is that code actually executing on the requests you expect? Have you looked at the raw response with a better tool like `curl` or `httpie` to verify the headers are present?

Answer (score 1):

The order that you add middleware in express is critical. You need to make sure your snippet above happens BEFORE all the rest of your app routes. It should be very soon after you initially create the `app` instance.

Comment: It is the first thing after i instantiate my ap